# Как реализовать линию, разделяющую кнопки CSS

Tags: html, css, css3

[image: 2 кнопки и линия между ними]

Есть данный макет. Вопрос заключается в том, как реализовать линию, разделяющую 2 кнопки, на CSS
Помимо того, желательно, чтобы она была адаптивна в том смысле, что если одна из кнопок будет по размеру больше, то линия примет соответствующую форму

UPD:

> то линия примет соответствующую форму

Здесь я имею ввиду, что она должна растянуться. Вот так:
[image: Кнопка побольше]

Comment: динамический патч в svg(скорее всего плохое решение, но почему нет?)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков А как реализовать то, что вы предложили?

Comment: Что именно из перечисленного? менять патч у свг? в js https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813931/change-svg-path-with-javascript

Comment: Как реализовать сам svg-патч? Я никогда еще сам не собирал свой svg-файл

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#кривые_безье

Comment: "то линия примет соответствующую форму" - стоит чётче определится с тем, как должна меняться форма.

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey обновил

Comment: Если делать через SVG, то вам нужно нарисовать две линии и одну кубическую кривую Безье (в центре). Опорные точки должны быть параллельны верхней и нижней линии, соответственно, и иметь равную длину. Такой конструкцией будет проще и понятнее управлять при изменении размеров.